# popup with bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

how can i create a popup with MVC bootstrap?

I have this code, when I click on "generate password" calls to a function (it´s in my controller Admin) and it returns me a string. How can i display the string in a popup window??

```
<div class="editor-field" title="User Password">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GeneratePsw", "Admin", null)'; return false;">
        <i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i> Generate password
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Bootstrap isn't an mvc framework.

Comment: I think he means http://mvcbootstrap.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-ShowPwdDialogUser", function () { 

    var pwd="";


    $.get("@Url.Action("GeneratePsw", "Admin")",function(data){

        pwd=data;

        $(".modal-body #pwdUser").val(pwd);
        $('#1').modal('show');


    }); 


})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since event listeners are better than click events, I'd probably do something like this:

```
<div class="editor-field" title="User Password">
    <a id="pwd_gen" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#">
        <i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i> Generate password
    </a> 
</div>

$(function() { // document.ready shorthand
    $('#pwd_gen').click(function() {
        var myPwd = $(this).location.href='@Url.Action("GeneratePsw", "Admin", null);
        alert(myPwd); // or however you want to handle it with Bootstrap
    });
});
```

Comment: it doesnt call to the function "GeneratePsw" must "$('#pwd_gen'...." be in @section onReady{ .... } ?? or where?? thank you!

Comment: I've added that to my answer and fixed syntax to close the click function properly.